# How to exit early from a python block inside vimscript

Tags: python, vim

I have a vim function with something like this

```
func! Foo()
python3 <<EOF
import yaml, sys
data = yaml.safe_load('@"')
if len(data) < 0:
  sys.exit(0)
# do more stuff on data
EOF
endfun
```

Obviously this does not work, I receive this error:

```
ch 3 was closed by the client
```

How to exit from python early from inside a vimscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really leave early, without generating an error (exception) that is caught by Vim.

Either use `if len(data) >= 0:` and indent the block that follows, or put everything inside a function, use `return` to bail out and call the function at the end of the block.